# Postgres function/procedure won't return value

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, functions, plpgsql

I'm new to PostgreSQL, coming from SQL server and I'm having trouble creating a function and/or procedure. First of all, may I just clarify that the only difference between a function and a procedure is indeed the support for transactions?

Now going back to my problem, I want a simple func/proc that returns the current connected user. Not using it anyhow, so any other example would work, it's only for learing the syntax as pgsql is different from t-sql. Here is my code, which I took from a tutorials website:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dev.get_user()
RETURNS VARCHAR AS $user$
DECLARE
    $user$ VARCHAR;
BEGIN
    SELECT current_user AS user;
    RETURN user; 
END;
$user$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I'm getting this and I don't know why:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "VARCHAR"
LINE 4:  $user$ VARCHAR;
```

If I remove line 4, it creates it successfully, but when I run it, it returns this error:

```
ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
HINT:  If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
```

I'm on pgsql 12.3, if it makes any difference. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> may I just clarify that the only difference between a function and a procedure is indeed the support for transactions?

No, the biggest difference is that functions are intended to return something while procedures are not.

In PL/pgSQL, the result of a SELECT statement needs to be stored somewhere (which is what the error message is telling you).

Variables are not defined with a `$` so the second `$user$` ends the string started with the first `$user$` which is why you get the first error.

So the correct way to write this would be:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dev.get_user()
  RETURNS VARCHAR AS $user$
declare
  l_user varchar
begin
  select current_user
     into l_user;
  return l_user;
end;
$user$
language plpgsql;
```

The SELECT isn't really necessary, you can assign a variable directly if you call a function (which `current_user` is):

```
begin
   l_user := current_user
   return l_user;
end;
```

The assignment using `:=` is faster then a `SELECT .. INTO`.

---

Note that the whole function can be simplified to:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dev.get_user()
  RETURNS VARCHAR 
AS 
$user$
  select current_user;
$user$
language sql;
```

For more details see the [PL/pgSQL reference](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html)

Comment: thank you very much, it's a lot clearer now. just a quick question though: the $user$ "tags" in your example (and mine) don't seem to relate to anything specific. can they be anything? can they be blank, so I'm left with $$ only? I don't see their value...

Comment: nevermind, I managed to read a few things in the documentation. those names define block boundaries as you can have more than one block in each func/proc. I managed to get my example working in more than one way, I guess I have to bite the bullet and read the entire documentation on syntax. thank you.

Comment: That's called [dollar quoting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING) - the body of a function or procedure is actually a string, but using dollar quoting makes it easier to write